# simple document/knowledge management system, based on django

Tags: django, knowledge-management

I'm looking for a simple document management system (preferably based on django).
Doing a quick internet research I found these two apps:

http://github.com/philippbosch/django-dms/tree/master/documents/

http://code.google.com/p/django-documents/

Has anyone ever tried one of this solutions, and can recommend one?

Can anyone recommend me another django-app that suits the following dms/kms needs:

- upload / download files
- browse files in a sharepoint like manner
- tag files and be able to search after tags
- add a short description to files

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try https://gitlab.com/mayan-edms/mayan-edms

Homepage at: http://www.mayan-edms.com

The project is also available via PyPI at: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mayan-edms/

Answer (score 0):

You can also try https://github.com/zapier/django-knowledge

And here is the documentation: http://django-knowledge.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Unfortunately I cannot seem to find the python version this code supports. The requirements say Django==1.5.1

Comment: Unfortunately this project is no longer maintained.